Density of $\{ \frac an : a \in A,\ n \in \mathbb N^*\}$ in $\mathbb R_+$ where $A \subset \mathbb R_+$ is unbounded
Let $A$ be an unbounded subset of $\mathbb R_+$. Consider
$$ B = \left\{ \frac an : a \in A,\ n \in \mathbb N^* \right\}$$
where $\mathbb N^*$ is the set of positive integers.
How to show that $B$ is dense in $\mathbb R_+$?

What are your thoughts/attempts? Please see here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question.

It suffices to show that
$$B^{-1}=\left\{\frac{n}{a}:a\in A,\ n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} $$
is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. To prove this, note that for each $a\in A$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, there is some integer $n\geq0$ such that
$$\frac{n}{a}\leq x<\frac{n+1}{a}=\alpha, $$
which implies that $|x-\alpha|\leq 1/a$ with $\alpha\in B^{-1}$. Since $A$ is unbounded, we may pick $a\in A$ so that $1/a$ is as small as we want.

You should refrain from answering low-quality questions.
